# ReactJS Exporting to Excel Sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, mapping

I'm trying to export a set of data to a excel sheet in my react application. I'm using `react-data-export` to do this.

https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/HEAD/examples/simple_excel_export_02.md

I'm mapping my data object as follows

```
const formData = [];

    pageFeedbackListData.map((data, key) => {

      formData.push([data.customer_contact,
        data.customer_name,
        data.form_name,
        data.optional_feedback,
        data.time,
        data.total_average])
    })
```

And using it like this

```
const dataSet1 = [{
      columns: ["Customer Contact", "Customer Name", "Form Name", "Optional Feedback", "Time", "Total Average"],
      data: [formData]
    }];
```

when i console my formData it gives a output like this

```
0: (6) ["ergerg", "ergeg", "Test", "wgrgegerg", 1565409622210, "4.3"]
1: (6) ["mali@gmail.com", "Mali", "Test", "Now you can browse privately, and other people who…downloads and bookmarks will be saved. Learn more", 1565409667623, "4.3"]
2: (6) ["N/A", "N/A", "Mali", "frwef", 1565409698437, "5.0"]
3: (6) ["N/A", "N/A", "Hotel", "Best
```

But my excel sheet works if i use like this

```
data: [formData[0],formData[1],formData[2],formData[3]]
```

How can i map my dataset so it produces a array like the above one without having to manually use array position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the way you pass the formData to the dataSet, you wrap your formData in additional array, but your formData already has a correct structure

```
const dataSet1 = [{
      columns: ["Customer Contact", "Customer Name", "Form Name", "Optional Feedback", "Time", "Total Average"],
      data: [formData]  //<----  here is the problem
    }];
```

just change it to

```
const dataSet1 = [{
      columns: ["Customer Contact", "Customer Name", "Form Name", "Optional Feedback", "Time", "Total Average"],
      data: formData
    }];
```

You are creating an array with all your formData at 0 index

Comment: I swear i tried removing it also.. It didn't work then :D Thank you it's working now